# Why reboots the system after a long hibernation?

Tags: arch-linux, hibernate

I set up my ASUS X551-CA laptop for hibernating. When tested hibernation, it worked but after a longer period (more than 10 minutes) the system resumes and instantly reboots with file system warnings of the journals. dmesg gave no useful informations, only informs about a succesful resume. The os is Arch Linux with kernel 4.4.5 and systemd 229.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When hibernating, there are various ways to "wake up" the system , in addition to the normal power button ; Eg LAN or USB.
[[ Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN & https://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times ]]
After it wakes up, kernel may have detected a faulty hibernate, which may potentially have corrupted the FileSystem , hence kernel triggers a crash or panic , which results in reboot.

Comment: So I would look for faults in the system logs and journals?

Comment: Yes. You should also check your OS settings & BIOS settings for "WAKE ON LAN" or anything related to hibernate+sleep. Check your system logs at hibernate and at wakeup. If possible, check the behaviour when booting+hibernating with some other OS. Also check if DISK Caching or DISK Flushing is behaving correctly at hibernate. Too many things to check !!!!

Comment: Now this was useful - I found that the hibernate script didn't do flushing, what caused the machine to reboot. THank you!

Comment: @ThomasBenko , Nice to know that your issue is resolved ! You may want to consider "accepting" this answer.

Comment: With some more experiment I found that pure flushing isn't enough. When the pre-hiernate and post-wakeup hardware environment isn't exactly the same, the sysfs gets confused and causes kernel panic. This is correct for a pc, but not for a laptop.